# named.service is failing to start

Tags: centos7, systemctl

This is the log. I don't know what problem is. I have checked many stack but I am not getting any solution.

```
    [root@srv ~]# systemctl status named.service
● named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-02-21 12:24:35 IST; 18s ago
Process: 1599 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z "$NAMEDCONF"; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 21 12:24:35 srv.fgngf.in bash[1599]: /var/named/domain1.com.db:14: ignoring out-of-zone data (ns1.fgngf.in)
Feb 21 12:24:35 srv.fgngf.in bash[1599]: /var/named/domain1.com.db:15: ignoring out-of-zone data (ns2.fgngf.in)
Feb 21 12:24:35 srv.fgngf.in bash[1599]: zone domain1.com/IN: loaded serial 2024022126
Feb 21 12:24:35 srv.fgngf.in bash[1599]: /var/named/domain2.com.db:14: ignoring out-of-zone data (ns1.fgngf.in)
Feb 21 12:24:35 srv.fgngf.in bash[1599]: /var/named/domain2.com.db:15: ignoring out-of-zone data (ns2.fgngf.in)
Feb 21 12:24:35 srv.fgngf.in bash[1599]: zone domain2.com/IN: loaded serial 2024022155
Feb 21 12:24:35 srv.fgngf.in systemd[1]: named.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 21 12:24:35 srv.fgngf.in systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Feb 21 12:24:35 srv.fgngf.in systemd[1]: Unit named.service entered failed state.
Feb 21 12:24:35 srv.fgngf.in systemd[1]: named.service failed.
```